# Xamarin, Viewpager using Fragments

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-viewpager

I have followed this tutorial (https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/Cheesesquare) for creating a Tab View with Viewpager.

The example works fine, but I want to add this code in another big project and my Fragment class already extends from another Fragment, so I cannot use this:

```
public class LoginFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
```

Do you have any solution?

Comment: *"so I cannot use this:"*, could you elaborate on what's the problem / error shown?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have add more information